# yii2 form file widget give validation error on every update

Tags: validation, model, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

model code :

```
[['thumbnail_image'], 'required', 'message' => 'Please upload an image.'],
```

view:

```
$form->field($model, 'thumbnail_image')->fileInput(['accept' => 'image/*', 'onchange' => 'readURL(this)'])->label('Thumbnail Image', ['class' => 'control-label thumbnail-image-class'])
```

File input forces uploading file with every update. even thumb image value available but it gives error to thumb image is required.

Comment: Welcome. Include source code (and may be screenshots) in your question  to other people can understand your problem. Provide source code of your model, controller action and view. See how to ask a question at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is my form code :- 
echo $form->field($model, 'thumbnail_image')->fileInput(['accept' => 'image/*', 'onchange' => 'readURL(this)'])->label('Thumbnail Image', ['class' => 'control-label thumbnail-image-class'])

and here is my model code :-

[['thumbnail_image'], 'required', 'message' => 'Please upload an image.'],

Comment: Please, put it to your question body and format as code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[['thumbnail_image'], 'required', 'message' => 'Please upload an image.', 'when' => function($model) {
        return  ($model->thumbnail_image) ? 0:1;
        }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
            if ($('#thumb_id').val() == '') {
               return 1;
            } else {
               return 0;
            }
        }"],
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed issue with conditional validation of YII2. we have to check on update record that thumb image exist or not. 0 for no required

```
[['thumbnail_image'], 'required', 'message' => 'Please upload an image.', 'when' => function($model) {
            return  ($model->thumbnail_image) ? 0:1;
            }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
                if ($('#thumb_id').val() == '') {
                   return 1;
                } else {
                   return 0;
                }
            }"],
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-imagevalidator.html) to validate images and `uploadRequired` property

```
[['thumbnail_image'], 'file', 'uploadRequired' => true', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
```

And read carefully http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html to properly implement file uploading